# Run multiple HTTPS servers with Express

Tags: node.js, express, https

How can I run more than 1 HTTPS server using Express? Is there any way to do that? I managed to get 1 HTTPS server to work with Express but second server doesn't seem to be that easy to set up.

Comment: Can you provide more details - where you are trying to run Node.JS - express server? Are you planning to host multiple web applications from one machine with SSL (HTTPS) connection?

Comment: @PrasadKothavale I want to run web server and a API on Express. Both need to be run over HTTPS. Web server must have HTTPS, obviously. And API needs to be run over HTTPS because when I am trying to request something from API over HTTP when i am connected with HTTPS, then I am getting error, that the content served over HTTP is blocked. I want to run it on 1 machine. I have 
SSL certificate that I can use.

Comment: What have you tried? The only thing you would need to do is start the second server using a different port. Be aware that using a different port means that the requests in the browser will be cross-domain and will need to honor CORS to work correctly. If you're already serving content from the first server why can't you have your APIs there as well?